# Querying by lightswitch field type in template

Tags: templating

I have a field (mdFeatured) set up as a lightswitch field type. I am trying to retrieve both featured and non-featured entries:

```
{% set featuredEntries = craft.entries.section('merchantDirectory').mdFeatured(true).relatedTo(category).find() %}
{% set normalEntries = craft.entries.section('merchantDirectory').mdFeatured(false).relatedTo(category).find() %}
```

The featured entries are being retrieved properly, but the normal entries are returning both featured entries and normal entries mixed together. Any possibly know why this is not working? I tried replacing "true" and "false" with "1" and "0" but that did not seem to work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try looking for an empty string: `mdFeatured('')` or prefix 1 or true with not: `mdFeatured('not 1')`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Still feels odd that "false" by itself does not work though.

Comment: This doesn't work in Craft 3. I've tried everything I can think of and still nothing. ```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages').hideFromNavigation('not 1') %}
'0'
false
``` No idea where to go from here.